# Google Analytics Data in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I am able to get the code example to work pulling in data from Google Analytics into Google Spreadsheet (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script)   However, I know the ID of the profile I want, I don't need to go through the overhead of getting the "first profile."  I can't get it working when I try to hard code an ID like this:

```js
function getReportDataForProfile() {

  var profileId = '12345678';
  var tableId = 'ga:12345678';
  var startDate = getLastNdays(14);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'sort': '-ga:visits,ga:keyword',         // Sort by visits descending, then keyword.
    'segment': 'dynamic::ga:isMobile==Yes',  // Process only mobile traffic.
    'filters': 'ga:source==google',          // Display only google traffic.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '250'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                  // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                  // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      'ga:visits,ga:pageviews', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No profiles found');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some details on the error? Are you sure you have the correct profile ID?

Answer (score 0):

The profile ID must be prefixed with ga:.

So in your case:

```
var profileId = '12345678'; should be:

var profileId = 'ga:12345678';
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids